# What does _ :: mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, lift

I am going through a book Lift in action and I encountered something I don't quite understand:  **_ ::**

```
object permanent_link extends MappedString(this, 150){
    override def validations =
    valMinLen(3, "Link URL must be at least 5 characters") _ ::
    super.validations
}
```

I can't find any hint so I would be grateful if anyone could help me out..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know Lift, but this is a general question. First of all, the `::` is a Scala cons operator:

```
scala> 1 :: 2 :: List(3, 4)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This means that `super.validations` is some sort of a sequence and `valMinLen(3, "Link URL must be at least 5 characters") _` is a single value in that list.

From the context it looks obvious that in overridden `validations` method they are calling `super` version *and* prepend some extra validation at the beginning.

This extra validation is created by a call to `valMinLen()`. However this extra call does not return an element matching the type of `validations` list - but a function. Instead of prepending the function value we are explicitly saying (by adding `_` suffix`) that we want to prepend a function itself, not a return value of that function.

Code snippet is worth a thousand words:

```
scala> def f = 3
f: Int

scala> def g = 4
g: Int

scala> val listOfInts = List(f, g)
listOfInts: List[Int] = List(3, 4)

scala> val listOfFunctions = List(f _, g _)
listOfFunctions: List[() => Int] = List(<function0>, <function0>)
```

Compare the type of `listOfInts` and `listOfFunctions`. I believe the `f _` syntax is called *partially applied function* in Scala world.

Answer (score 5):

The underscore ignifies that valMinLen isn't to be called but be used as a function "pointer".

The `::` operator concatenates lists.

It would in other words seem like the code builds a list `validations` that consist of a function "pointer" to `valMinLen` with the parameters given and the rest of the list is the value of `super.validations`, that is the super class' validations.

I'm sure someone will correct my terminology here :)

Answer (score 0):

The code might be more readable with some proper indentation and introducing a val:

```
object permanent_link extends MappedString(this, 150) {

  override def validations = minimumValidation :: super.validations

  val minimumValidation = valMinLen(3,"Link URL must be at least 5 characters") _
}
```

So as noted before, the `::` operator just prepends a new element to a list, the `_` has nothing to do with it and is used to obtain a function object, like in

```
(1 :: 2 :: Nil) map (println _)
```

which makes a list [1, 2] and applies the function println to every element (the underscore can actually be omitted here). The object `println _` constructs a function object from the `println` method with the `_` representing the function's single parameter.

Comment: So you can reference `minimumValidation` before you have declared it?

Comment: Declaration order does not matter in scala, it doesn't in most current languages.